# Nullcheck of status at line 114 of value previously dereferenced in Sonar

Tags: java, sonarlint

For the below piece of code  Sonar throws me a critical violation - Correctness - Nullcheck of status value previously dereferenced

Can someone suggest on this on what am I doing wrong here?

### code

```
public boolean isExactMacthBill(AddressResponse response) {
        boolean exactMatch = false;
        if (null != response && null != response.getHostResponse()) {
            HostResponseDetail hostResponse = response.getHostResponse();
            String addressStatus = hostResponse.getMatchStatus();
            ResponseDetail status = hostResponse.getStatus();
            String addressMatchCode = status.getCode();
            if (null != response.getMatchedAddresses() && response.getMatchedAddresses().size() > 0 && status != null) {
                if (addressStatus.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.USPS_MATCH)
                        || (addressStatus.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.PARTIAL_MATCH)
                                && addressMatchCode.equalsIgnoreCase("3SXU"))) {
                    exactMatch = true;
                } else
                    exactMatch = false;
            }
        }
        return exactMatch;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You are checking `status != null`, but on the line before you have `status.getCode()`. `status` can not be null in your if statement.

Answer (score 5):

The actual problem is in the line after the highlighted one - you've got:

```java
if (... && status != null)
```

Just remove that check and I think SonarLint will be happy. It unnecessary, because if `status` is null then `status.getCode()` will already have thrown an exception before you reach that condition.

Fundamentally, you need to know whether `getStatus()` *should* ever return null - whether you have to handle that situation explicitly. If you do, you should check it *before* your call to `status.getCode()`, and react accordingly. If you don't, it's fine to call the `getCode()` method - if your assumption is incorrect, you'll get a `NullPointerException` as normal, which is probably the most appropriate result for the scenario of "the world isn't as I expect it to be". But you shouldn't try to "handle" it being null after you've already depended on it being non-null.

Answer (score 1):

status can be null when it is received from `hostResponse.getStatus();`; so when the line `String addressMatchCode = status.getCode();` is called it can result in a Null Reference Exception.

You should verify all the variables if there are null before calling methods on them.

Comment: While what you wrote is correct, that is not the reason for that Sonar "complaint". See the answer by Jon Skeet.

Comment: "You should verify all the variables if there are null before calling methods on them." I disagree strongly with this. If the return value from `getStatus()` is documented to not return null, it's fine to assume it *is* non-null... if it throws an exception, so be it. That's probably what you'd want to do with the explicit check anyway: "The system isn't behaving as I expect it to. Panic!" The reason SonarLint is complaining is because the code is inconsistent in its expecations.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `addressMatchCode` inside your if condition which null check the status.

```
public boolean isExactMacthBill(AddressResponse response) {
    boolean exactMatch = false;
    if (null != response && null != response.getHostResponse()) {
        HostResponseDetail hostResponse = response.getHostResponse();
        String addressStatus = hostResponse.getMatchStatus();
        ResponseDetail status = hostResponse.getStatus();

        if (null != response.getMatchedAddresses() && response.getMatchedAddresses().size() > 0 && status != null) {
            String addressMatchCode = status.getCode();
            if (addressStatus.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.USPS_MATCH)
                    || (addressStatus.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.PARTIAL_MATCH)
                            && addressMatchCode.equalsIgnoreCase("3SXU"))) {
                exactMatch = true;
            } else
                exactMatch = false;
        }
    }
    return exactMatch;
}
```